# I can't find file "gbsnuf9"

Tags: errors

I'm generating one chinese report and getting following error.

Part of my code:

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}
  some chinese text

\clearpage\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

Error Message:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexmf gbsnuf9
! I can't find file `gbsnuf9'.
<*> ...=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input gbsnuf9

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input gbsnuf9
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: We need more information. Please provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With TeX Live 2013 your code snippet works well:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}
  some chinese text

\clearpage\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```